# jQuery - conditionally append HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to append a picture of a magnify glass after each image within a div. And some of them are linked and in that case I would like it to append it after the `</a>` that follows the `img` tag.

How can I make:

```
<img src="a.jpg" .... />
```

turn into:

```
<img src="a.jpg"><img src="mag.gif" />
```

And:

```
<a href="...."><img src="a.jpg" .... /></a>
```

turn into:

```
<a href="...."><img src="a.jpg"></a><img src="mag.gif" />
```

Note that there might be linebreaks before and after the `img` tags.

How is that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each($('img[src="a.jpg"]'), function(i) {
    var $element = $(this);
    if($element.parent('a').length) {
        $element = $element.parent();
    }
    $element.after('<img src="mag.gif"/>');
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vZaQu/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `after` method.

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$('img').after('<img src="mag.gif"/>')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('img[src="a.jpg"]').after('<img src="mag.gif" />');
```

This will add magnify glass image after each image with `src="a.jpg"`.

Read about jQuery ***[`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)*** method.

You can also use ***[`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)*** like below:

```
$('<img src="mag.gif" />').insertAfter('img[src="a.jpg"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code:

```
$('img').parent().not('a').children('img:first').after('<img src="mag.gif" />')​;
$('img').parents('a:first').after('<img src="mag.gif" />');
```

A working demo is at http://jsfiddle.net/sURqy/.

Answer (score 1):

### This solves your conditional logic

```
var $a_with_img = $('a').has('img');
var $img_no_a = $('img').not('a img');
var $elements = $.merge($img_no_a, $a_with_img);
$elements.after('<img src="mag.gif" />');​
```